# Blazor API sometimes returns a 404 Not Found Error

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a Blazor Web App that uses an API to change some table values on an SQL database. However, the service sometimes returns a 404 error with the message:

> "'<' is an invalid start of a value".

But most of the times the service does work and finds the endpoint without a problem. And by the time the error appears, it fixes itself on its own after some time. Any idea why this happens and how to stop it from happening?

I've tried adding exceptions to catch the problem and somehow work around that. But still, I just wan to understand why this is happening. Changing the name of the method works temporarily, but the problem inevitably returns.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-howto-troubleshoot-guide#404-returned-for-client-requests

Comment: @jdweng a link alone isn't really a very good answer.  Assume the OP has access to Google, and say something about it.